# Rails User Comments on Movies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, associations

I have three scaffolds
**Users**, *Comments* and `Movies`

In my app, I want **Users** to *Comment* on `Movies`, and different users can *Comment* on a `Movie` page.

How would i create the associations code that lets users add comments on movies and then on the movie page display all comments? COuld you please also tell me the code to count the comments, so show how many comments there are and display them in integers

What i've got so far

Comments table with Subject and Body
Movies table
Users table

user.rb

```
has_many: comments
```

movies.rb

```
has_many: comments
```

comments.rb

```
belongs_to :users
belongs_to :movies
```

Thanks !

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 2):

The associations you would need is to tell what they belong to. so you would need to do the following in the models:

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

Movie Model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

You would need to generate migrations to add the foreign key columns to the comment table. Once you have that, all you need to do is attach the comments to the movies and users through their id. Then to have them the comments display, in the view:

```
<% @movie.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.text %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: To create a comment, you would need a link to add a new comment. in the view:

```
<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_movie_comment_path(@movie) %>
```

That should take you to the new comment view and the form for it. In the form, you can associate the comment to the user by setting a hidden field that associates the user to the comment. In the comment form view:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :user %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :comment, :user_id, current_user_id %>
<% end %>
```

The last part assumes you have a session active.

EDIT 2:

In the routes, you would nest the comments resource inside the movies resource:

```
resources :movies do
  resources :comments
end
```

EDIT 3:

In your comments controller, you'll have to point the actions to the movie. In the controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_movie

  private
    def load_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    end
```

The private section needs to be at the bottom of the controller. With that done, update the actions to use the @movie.

```
def index
  @comments = @movie.comments.all
end
```

Do that for show, new, etc actions in the controller. In the create action and update action, you'll need to update the html redirect.

```
format.html { redirect_to (@movie, @comment), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
```

and

```
format.html { redirect_to (@movie, @comment), notice: 'Comment was successfully Updated.' }
```

Comment: Yes but how would A user CREATE a comment and then make it BELONG to a movie

Comment: But with this code that you just edited, would it make the comment BELONG to the movie ?

Comment: Using movie_id, just like we are using user_id

Comment: That is already handled in the link_to. It creates a movie.comment(id) for that particular movie. The @movie is the specific instance of the movie model you are working with.

Comment: In the routes.rb, what would the new_movie_comment_path be ?

Comment: Ok so This works now but when I click on the link_to and create the comment, I must specify the movie_id, how would I do that automatically without the comment creator (user) specify the movie name or Id

Comment: You don't need to do `find_by_id`.  `find` searches by `id` by default.  `Movie.find(params[:movie_id]` would suffice.

Comment: Help Anyone!
I get this error when creating a new Comment



/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:56: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...mat.html { redirect_to (@movie, @comment), notice: 'Comment ...

Comment: and when i create a movie, i still have to specify a movie_id

Comment: Try changing the .find_by_id to the .find(params[:movie_id]) as shown by Sean Hill. Can you post the error in an edit of your question so I can see the full error? I have updated my answer to reflect Sean Hill's contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You may have :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Comment< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end

class Movies< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In yours views you can do something like :

```
Number of comments : <%= @movie.comments.length %>
<% @movie.comments.each do |comment| %>
  Pseudo : <%= comment.user.pseudo%>
  Body : <%= comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

If you start with Rails you should take a look at this [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning). It's awesome for basics ;)

Comment: How to I let a user CREATE a comment on a MOVIE PAGE

Comment: There are a lot of solutions ! Do you want use ajax to add comment dynamically ?
To manage user authentication I suggest you to use gem Devise. After that in your Comment controller you can do : @comment = Comment.build(:body => params["body"], :user => current_user)

Answer (score 0):

In users.rb

```
has_many :movies, through: :comments
```

In movies.rb

```
has_many :users, through: comments
```

This is called a **has-many-through** association. Reference [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

To count:

```
number_of_comments = Comment.all.size
number_of_comments_on_a_movie = Movie.find(movie_id).comments.size
number_of_comments_by_a_user = User.find(user_id).comments.size
```